# How to check empty spaces in java

Tags: java

```
String selectedVal = "";

for (SelectItem item : filterItems) {
                selectedVal = item.getValue().toString();
                break;
            }
```

I am getting selectedVal="            " how to check this empty space in java.

I tried with if(!selectedVal.equals("") and if(!selectedVal.isEmpty()) but condition getting true.How to check more than one empty space ?

Answer (score 9):

You can `trim()` your string before checking with `isEmpty()`

```
boolean isEmpty = myString.trim().isEmpty();
```

Beware of `isEmpty()`, it's only available since Java SE 6

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - String.trim()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())
- [javadoc - String.isEmpty()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

Comment: If isEmpty() is not available, you can also check the String length: if (s.length() == 0) {}

Answer (score 8):

I use this all the time:

```
public static boolean isBlank(String s)
{
    return (s == null) || (s.trim().length() == 0);
}
```

Returns `true` on null, empty string, or whitespace only.

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple test, using an external library is not a good idea, but if you need String manipulation (left and right padding, etc.), you can go for [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and the 
*StringUtils.isEmpty()* method.

More recently, you can use the [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) library and the class *Strings*. This library has a lot of usefull util methods (null handling, etc.). Once again, use this library only if you have others needs than checking empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

boolean isEmpty = myString.toString().trim().isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

I use a routine similar to what Grodriguez posted.  It ends up in a `util/BagOTricks.java` file in every project.  My routine does a similar check and returns a null as a space, or the trimmed input string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java programmer, but with regex, [\s](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/) means white space.

[**This**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Blankstringemptyorwhitespace.htm) link might also be useful:

```
 /**
   * Helper function for making null strings safe for comparisons, etc.
   *
   * @return (s == null) ? "" : s;
   */
  public static String makeSafe(String s) {
    return (s == null) ? "" : s;
  }

/**
   * Helper function for null, empty, and whitespace string testing.
   *
   * @return true if s == null or s.equals("") or s contains only whitespace
   *         characters.
   */
  public static boolean isEmptyOrWhitespace(String s) {
    s = makeSafe(s);
    for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; i++) {
      if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Why regexes when you don't have a regular expression ?

Comment: @Colin Hebert: He wants to test for a condition of "only space(s)." That's a classic 1:1 correspondence to a regexp, in my view. Especially if it turns out his data contains whitespace characters other than space. Shimmy's procedural solution probably works well enough and certainly has better performance, but it's far from an elegant translation of the problem.

Comment: can you expand on what the `makeSafe` method does?

Comment: I am not in the java business anyway, just googled around and that's what I've found, I am a .NET user where the IsNullOrWhiteSpace method is out-the-box (in .NET 4), otherwise I would've checked isnull->trim->length. Also in .NET there are extension methods which make the solution much more convenient.

Comment: @fahd, as I said, I am not a java programmer at all, and as stated in my post, the code is taken from the link above it: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Blankstringemptyorwhitespace.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
public boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
    return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Method returns true when passed string is null or empty / only contains blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Apache Commons Lang library, you can use [`StringUtils.isEmpty()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String)) to check if a String is empty ("") or null, and [`StringUtils.isBlank()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)) to check if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

Note the differences:

isEmpty()

```
StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true
StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false
StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false
StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
```

isBlank()

```
StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```