# How to Check for empty line while parsing csv file?

Tags: java

From third party daily reports i will be getting a similar kind of  csv file as shown below

```
07-Jan-2016
It is better to lead from behind and to put others in front, especially when you celebrate victory when nice things occur. You take the front line when there is danger. Then people will appreciate your leadership.

The main thing that you have to remember on this journey is, just be nice to everyone and always smile.
```

My requirement is that i need to put each paragraph (A line after space) each quote for above reference in a separate StringBuffer

My question how can i check for empty line ??

I tried with

```
if(line.contains("            "))
{
System.out.println("hjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjk");
}
```

But the above is causing issue where ever there is a space

I am reading the csv file as shown below

```
 String csvFile = "ip/ASRER070116.csv";
  BufferedReader br = null;
  String line = "";
  try {
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith(",")) {
     line = line.replaceFirst(",", "");
    }
    System.out.println(line);
   }
  }
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve this ??

Comment: You can check if all the chars in the line (if any) are spaces and/or carriage returns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check empty spaces in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745421/how-to-check-empty-spaces-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (line != null && (line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n"))){
   System.out.println("this is empty line");
}
```

Comment: @Preethi Jain pl accept the answer if it really worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `trim()` on the read line and then check if `line.length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringUtils.isBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

> public static boolean isBlank(CharSequence cs)
>
> Checks if a CharSequence is whitespace, empty ("") or null.
>
> ```
>  StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
>  StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
>  StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
>  StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
>  StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
> ```